# Python Tornado - How to Implement Long-Polling Server to Read from a Queue

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to build a web server to collect "commands" via AJAX and then distribute the commands to clients via long-polling.

The goal is that someone POSTs some data to /add-command.

Another client implements a long-polling client hitting /poll waiting for a command to execute.

I think a queue is the right data structure to use to hold commands waiting for attention. I'd like the commands to essentially be distributed immediately to any long-polling client but held if no client is currently polling.

Here's my python script.

```
import os
import time
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import Queue
import multiprocessing.pool
import mysql.connector
import urlparse
import uuid
import json

_commandQueue = Queue.Queue()
_commandPollInterval = 0.2
_commandPollTimeout = 10

class HomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("home.htm")

class AddCommandHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        d = urlparse.parse_qs(self.request.body)
        _commandQueue.put(d)
        self.write(str(True))

class PollHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("start")
        d = 1
        d = yield self.getCommand()
        self.write(str(d))
        self.write("end")
        self.finish()
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def getCommand(self):
        start = time.time()
        while (time.time() - start) < _commandPollTimeout * 1000:
            if not _commandQueue.empty:
                return _commandQueue.get()
            else:
                time.sleep(_commandPollInterval)
        return None 

def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
            (r"/add-command", AddCommandHandler),
            (r"/poll", PollHandler),
        ], 
        debug=True, 
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    )
    tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application).listen(int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `AddCommandHandler` works fine to put items in the `_commandQueue`.

The `PollHandler` request just times out. If I call the `PollHandler`, it seems to lock the `_commandQueue` and I can't put or get from it.

I suspect I need to join the queue, but I can't seem to find the right time to do that in the code.

UPDATE -- Here's my final code thanks to the answers

```
import os
import time
import datetime
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import tornado.queues
import urlparse
import json

_commandQueue = tornado.queues.Queue()
_commandPollInterval = 0.2
_commandPollTimeout = 10

class HomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("home.htm")

class AddCommandHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        cmd = urlparse.parse_qs(self.request.body)
        _commandQueue.put(cmd)
        self.write(str(cmd))
    def post(self):
        cmd = urlparse.parse_qs(self.request.body)
        _commandQueue.put(cmd)
        self.write(str(cmd))

class PollHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        cmd = yield self.getCommand()
        self.write(str(cmd))
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def getCommand(self):
        try:
            cmd = yield _commandQueue.get(
                timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=_commandPollTimeout)
            )
            raise tornado.gen.Return(cmd)
        except tornado.gen.TimeoutError:
            raise tornado.gen.Return()

def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
            (r"/add-command", AddCommandHandler),
            (r"/poll", PollHandler),
        ], 
        debug=True, 
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    )
    tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application).listen(int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In async model you should omit blocking operation, `time.sleep` is evil in your code. Moreover, I think that the best way is to use tornado's (in async interface) queue - [`tornado.queue.Queue`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue) and use async get:

```
import datetime
import tornado.gen
import tornado.queues

_commandQueue = tornado.queues.Queue()


    # ...rest of the code ...

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def getCommand(self):
        try:
            # wait for queue item if cannot obtain in timeout raise exception
            cmd = yield _commandQueue.get(
                timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=_commandPollTimeout)
            )
            return cmd
        except tornado.gen.Timeout:
            return None
```

Note: Module `tornado.queues` si available since Tornado 4.x, if you use older one, [Toro](https://toro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will help.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. Here are a couple of minor corrections. it should be tornado.queues.Queue. You also can't return from a coroutine, so instead I had to raise tornado.gen.Return(cmd). Thanks much, I was so stuck.

Comment: I've updated according to your comment. `return` is valid in coroutine (generator functions) since python 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You **can NOT** use sleep in listener, since it blocks reading from input stream. `time.sleep(_commandPollInterval)`. What you **should use** is `yield gen.sleep(_commandPollInterval)`