# Does CherryPy support long-polling enabled paths in its servers well?

Tags: cherrypy, long-polling

I am newbie to Cherrypy. I've done some research with google but didn't find much information.
I know that in order for a server to support long-polling it has to be threaded. I've heard much about Python servers generally not very good at this, and some article suggest using [Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418332/python-tornado-how-to-implement-long-polling-server-to-read-from-a-queue). However, I noticed that Cherrypy does support multiple threads. I'm not sure what it can or can't do compared to Tornado.

My use case is like this: The frontend will request long-polling to the backend to see if there is any new members update. Such updates are not frequent. Only occasionally there are some updates from backend database, and the frontend should update many fields accordingly.

Could someone please give a simple code example using cherrypy, or point a direction to read? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is somewhat [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but let me tell you, that you can use WebSockets with CherryPy, which normally makes long-polling superflous, because with WebSockets the server can actively send data to the clients.

Comment: @MikeScotty WebSockets are kind of overkill for very infrequent updates.